# ASP / VBScript - formatnumber if value is empty

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

On one of our ASP pages we have a table returning values from sql. However, when formating the number using FormatNumber and the field is empty  i get a "Type mismatch: 'FormatNumber' " is there a way around it?

example

```
td width="200" align="center" class="style1">&pound<%=FormatNumber (rs("Value_01"),0)%></td>
```

i have tried to use an IsNull but it fell over with

*"Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01c2'
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'IsNull'
/test.asp, line 87"*

```
<%=IIF(IsNull(rs("Value_01"),"0" ,FormatNumber (rs("Value_01"),0)))%>
```

btw if you havent guessed - im fairly green to ASP

Comment: You are missing closing paren on `IsNull`

Comment: where abouts? @Abhitalks

Comment: It should be `IsNull(rs("Value_01"))...`